# API update endpoint with Passport API authentication

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-passport, laravel-5.8

I have implemented API authentication using Laravel Passport successfully & want the authenticated user to update their personal info. So I have created an API endpoint `Route::put('user', 'UserController@updatePersonalInfo')`

The `updatePersonalInfo()` method of the controller looks like this

```
/**
* only authenticated user can update personal info
*
* api authentication by Passport
*/
public function updatePersonalInfo(Request $request)
{
    // check for the authenticated user
    $user = auth()->user();

    if ($user) {
        // get user sex & dob input, then update the sex & dob 
        $user->update($request->only(['sex', 'dob']));

        // return the updated user
        return new UserResource($user);
    }
}
```

Tested the API endpoint in Postman by passing in the bearer token and form values but the fields are not updated and I get back the same user records with no update.

I can't spot the reason, need help to figure out what the issue is.

Comment: Not much to go on. Hard to debug your code from here. Have you checked the logs? Is it an authentication issue? How far does the code get?

Comment: No it's not an authentication issue. The user resource is actually returned for the authenticated user.

Comment: Possibly, but none is thrown.

Comment: And nothing at all in the logs? I'd set a break point where the insert is supposed to go down and see what the heck your code is actually doing. Maybe you never try and persist a change? I don't know, can't see that code. Maybe you handle an insert exception and thus "nothing" happens...

Comment: @ficuscr I found nothing in the logs, I am clueless right now. I'll keep checking

Comment: you can try `dd($user);` right after update to check object class

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, if you want only the authenticated users to use this endpoint, use the 'auth:api' middleware:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function () {
    // Your endpoints here
});
```

Secondly, when dealing with API and Passport you can get the current user from the $request variable:

```
$request->user();
```